# Is there a way to disable all keyboard backlighting on an HP Spectre?

Tags: keyboard, backlight

I recently purchased a laptop with some unfavorable backlighting behavior. The <kbd>F5</kbd> key is permanently backlit at all times.  I was told that there is no way to turn off the F5 light.  But is there a way to completely disable **ALL** keyboard backlighting, perhaps by changing the BIOS, registry, or drivers?

I have an HP Spectre x360, by the way.

Comment: This would depend on the model of computer you have. If you could list some more information such as model, os, etc, you'll have a better chance of getting a response.

Comment: i used a small piece of duct tape, literally

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard backlighting state can be toggled using <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>.

Comment: the `F5` key still stays lit when the rest of the keys are off

Answer (score 0):

After enough complaints, it looks like HP has finally released a solution. There are updated drivers, and you can go into the bios to disable the key.
See below for details:
http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/Turn-off-permanent-backlight-under-F5-key-on-Spectre-x360/td-p/4968500